# Why am I seeing "No module named '_tkinter" when I deploy django to heroku?

Tags: python, html, django, tkinter, heroku

django works well on my local machine. But, when I deploy it to heroku, I see "ModuleNotFoundError" "No module named '_tkinter'". Though,  I never imported "_tkinter" or "tkinter" in my code. Your help will be appreciated. Thank you.

> ModuleNotFoundError at /

No module named '_tkinter'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    https://howididit.herokuapp.com/
Django Version:     4.0.6
Exception Type:     ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:

No module named '_tkinter'

Exception Location:     /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/tkinter/**init**.py, line 37, in 
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version:     3.10.5
Python Path:

['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
'/app',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python310.zip',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages']

Comment: In `/app/home/forms.py` you use `from turtle import title`. turtle is a python module which uses tkinter, hence the error. Change the name of the turtle file to something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Tkinter, just remove it from `/forms.py.` otherwise it'll be imported.

If you want to use tkinter,then consider the below process

please try adding tkinter to your requirements.txt. If it fails, even after that, check if you have added Python buildpack. If both the cases pass, try shelling into your Heroku instances and run the following command:

```bash
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

This will install Tkinter library in your instance of Heroku. That will resolve your error.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn;t work. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: Installing it on heroku may solve the import error but the program likely still won't run. Tkinter isn't designed to be run in a web app, and won't run in a web app without a lot of work.

Comment: Did you check out your code and push it to GitHub? @BaboucarrBadjie. The redeployment then should work (assuming you've removed it from forms.py)

Answer (score 0):

I found out these `from pyexpat import model  from turtle import title  from attr import fields` where imported in my forms.py. After deleting them, The problem was solved. Again, thank you all guys for your time, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so for anyone looking at this in the future and banging their head against the desk...this is what worked for me:

I started with a new Hello World app and started adding bits of my original code until i got to the error

found out that one of the modules I was using : icu, was using tkinter and i needed to install the Pyicu module instead

pip installed directly into heroku bash console instead of through my app

None of the answers i found online had worked for me, and I think its because this error isnt from having tkinter directly in your app, but from another module thats calling it.

When in doubt do what I did and start a new project from scratch and add chunks of code until you get the error to see which module is creating it

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to change DEBUG to False in your settings file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32801146)